# R Transpose A column into a Binary Row

Tags: sql, r, transpose

I have a single data column that looks like this for "one record"
There can be hundreds if not thousands of records where each record has a different ID but many different attributes ColName2
I want to transpose the table so it looks like table 2
Is this possible in R. It is possible in Rapid-miner but i would like to implement it in R

**What I have Table 1**

- ID   ColName2
- 1A   Item1
- 1A   Item2
- 1A   Item3
- 1A   Item4
- 2A   Item5

**What I want - Table 2**

- ID Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item 5
- 1A 1     1     1     1     0
- 2A 0     0     0     0     1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reshape2` for this, for example:

```
> df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("1A", 4), "2A"), ColName = 1:5)
> df
#  ID ColName
#1 1A       1
#2 1A       2
#3 1A       3
#4 1A       4
#5 2A       5

library(reshape2)

> df2 <- dcast(df, ID ~ ColName, fun.aggregate = any, value.var = "ColName")
```

The result of this reshapeing is:

```
  ID     1     2     3     4     5
1 1A  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2 2A FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

So you have logical values (TRUE where you want 1 and FALSE where you want 0). Since you can convert logical values to numeric, where TRUE == 1 and FALSE == 0, you just need to convert all columns (except the first) to numeric. To do this, you can use `lapply` on the data.frame except the first column (indicated by df2[-1]) and apply the function `as.numeric` to each of the other columns:

```
> df2[-1] <- lapply(df2[-1], as.numeric)
> df2
#  ID 1 2 3 4 5
#1 1A 1 1 1 1 0
#2 2A 0 0 0 0 1
```

`lapply` is often quite useful if you want to apply a function to all columns of a data.frame or all elements in a list. For some more information check out `?lapply` and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @beginneR. Can you explain to me whats happening on the line df2[-1] <- lapply(df2[-1], as.numeric)

Comment: @JohnSmith, I added an explanation. Hope this helps you understand what's happening :)

Comment: perfect thank you very much. I am receiving an error "Error in Summary.factor(integer(0), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  any not meaningful for factors" but i was able to run your code and it has put me in the right direction

Comment: @JohnSmith, in that case try `df2 <- dcast(df, ID ~ ColName, value.var = "ColName")` and then `df2[-1] <- lapply(df2[-1], function(x) as.numeric(!is.na(x)))`. Does that work?

Comment: yep...perfectly...Thanks again, without your help i would have been here until christmas